# Is there a way to turn off sections of script without just hiding it in comments?

Tags: autohotkey

So I have built some custom macros within my main script (where I cobble together my usual tools) triggered by hotkeys. I am starting to accumulate these macros and would like to turn off certain sections of the script so I can use the hotkey again and can collapse the code section in my editor. I don't want to create separate scripts for these custom functions (no particular reason tbh).

I have tried wrapping the section of script in an if statement but it simply executes the code regardless of the condition (see below)

```
if(0){
   ^!s::
        <my script>
   return
}
```

From how I understand it the ^!s:: hotkey is compiled even if it is within a failed conditional and triggers the actions of the script regardless. Would this be the correct understanding? Is there a way to "turn off" that section of script without commenting it out?

Comment: Just a note about your code snippet, you need to have a `#` in front of the `if` for it to work that way (also braces aren't required, see link). More info here: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm

Comment: `#If` or `Hotkey, If, [..]` is definitely the way to go if you want conditional hotkeys.

Comment: You could also just wrap everything in `/*` multiline `*/` comments, if you're editing the script anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EJE & @Joe DF

I believe the `#If` was what I was looking for. Thank you.